# Spark Windowing how to avoid reshuffle

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Have few below questions regarding Spark Windowing reshuffle:

1. If a DataFrame is already repartitioned on a column say "**id**", and if the same column is used in Window.partitionBy("**id**"), will there be a reshuffle happening? How can we avoid reshuffle here?
2. If we have 2 Windows say Window.partitionBy("**id**","**name**").orderBy("**salary**") and Window.partitionBy("**id**","**age**").orderBy("**salary**"). Where there first partition column is same.
   In second case, hopefully there won't be any reshuffle but sorting to happen only on columns which is in partitionBy and orderBy Or all the columns within DataFrame partition will be sorted again?

Answer (score 0):

use `.explain()` and look at `physical plan`.

**Q1**: No reshuffle evident.

**Q2**: Reshuffle evident. Stands to reason as to complex to split out and could not be done in parallel I suspect.

Used this:

```
val w = org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window.partitionBy("id", "line").orderBy("xtra")
val w2 = org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window.partitionBy("id", "xtra").orderBy("line")

val df3 = df2.withColumn("next", lead("line", 1, null).over(w)).withColumn("next2", lead("line", 1, null).over(w2)).explain(true)

== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false

 +- Window [id#524, line#525, xtra#526, next#530, lead(line#525, 1, null) 
   windowspecdefinition(id#524, xtra#526, line#525 ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, 1, 1)) AS next2#535], [id#524, xtra#526], [line#525 ASC NULLS FIRST]
   +- Sort [id#524 ASC NULLS FIRST, xtra#526 ASC NULLS FIRST, line#525 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
  +- Window [id#524, line#525, xtra#526, lead(line#525, 1, null) windowspecdefinition(id#524, line#525, xtra#526 ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, 1, 1)) AS next#530], [id#524, line#525], [xtra#526 ASC NULLS FIRST]
     +- Sort [id#524 ASC NULLS FIRST, line#525 ASC NULLS FIRST, xtra#526 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
        +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#524, 20), REPARTITION_BY_NUM, [id=#955]
           +- LocalTableScan [id#524, line#525, xtra#526]
```